# Processing a form with multiple multiple selects

Tags: php, html, html-select

I have a form for registering people to events, while the user can add or remove registered people - the number of inputs is dynamic.
Now, the regular inputs are easy to process, it's just

```
<input type="text" name="first_name[]">
```

And I process it as an array in a loop for each participant.
However, I need to have a multiple select input for each person, like

```
<select multiple name="extras[]">
<option value="42">Some extra feature</option>
...</select>
```

But that of course puts all the selected options into one array and I can't recognize which user picked which options.
I also tried `name="extras[][]"`, but that just puts each value into a separate array.
How can I make the form/the PHP script a way that I can tell who chose what?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send user specific info with option value like

```
<select multiple name="extras[]">
    <option value="42###USER_ID">Some extra feature</option>
</select>
```

then explode it on your php script like

```
foreach($_POST["extras"] as $a->$b){
   $userAndExtras = explode("###",$b);
   $userId = $userAndExtras[1]; // gives USER_ID
   $anotherValue = $userAndExtras[0]; // gives 42 or something like that

}
```

--

or use hidden fields

Comment: Surprisingly simple, yet efficient. Thanks!